# ExtentReports is displayed blank in Jenkins although the html file is created fine locally

Tags: jenkins, extentreports

I'm using Maven Project job with ExtentReports. At the end of job in console, I get messages.

```
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\vladi\git\Advanced-Tricks-for-Selenium-and-JUnit5\AdvancedSeleniumAndJUnit\pom.xml to com.java/AdvancedSeleniumAndJUnit/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/AdvancedSeleniumAndJUnit-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level C:\Users\vladi\git\Advanced-Tricks-for-Selenium-and-JUnit5\AdvancedSeleniumAndJUnit\test-output to C:\Users\vladi\.jenkins\jobs\ExtentReports\htmlreports\ExtentReport
```

No error messages. But the ExtentReport is blank. C:\Users\vladi.jenkins\jobs\ExtentReports\htmlreports\ExtentReport contains two files **testReport.html** and **htmlpublisher-wrapper.html**. **testReport.html** contains nice report with the screenshots on failures, but **htmlpublisher-wrapper.html** is blank.

Here is my settings
[image]

What is wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I changed Index Pages to *.html and Index page title to ExtentReport. Now the ExtentReport is displayed but witout any styling and screenshots are broken.

Comment: Found half a solution. If you run Jenking with 'java -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="" -jar jenkins.war' the reports are displayed, but still with broken screenshots.